# How to check presence of a URL parameter compared to an Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Given these two sample urls and code.  How can I use the Array as a reference to check if the values are in the UTM parameter? (There will ONLY be one utm parameter at any given time).
example.com?utm=test
example.com?utm=test2

var partnerArray = ["test", 'test2'];

```
function findPartner() { 
    if window.location.href.indexOf('?utm='(partnerArray)' !== -1) {
        //do something fun here
    }
```

I know my code is wrong - I haven't found example of using an Array to check for values in the URL.

Thank you.

Comment: Provided you grab the value from the url first, you can use `partnerArray.includes(utm);` (always try to break up your problem into its parts; part 1 is extracting the value from the URL, part 2 is checking if the resulting string is in the array; the existing solution you were looking for is too specific, but the two parts all have tons of existing solutions which can be easily found)

Comment: @ChrisG The values in the Array will be known to me.  I can find if the url contains a parameter with this: '''(window.location.href.indexOf('?utm=test') > 0)'''  -- but that's one specific value for the UTM.  I need to check it against a know list (the Array).  That's the part of the puzzle I'm missing.

Comment: Please read my comment again. You need to extract the value of the URL's `utm` parameter first. Once you have that, i.e. once you have `test`, checking it against the array is trivial. You're stuck on your flawed approach.

Comment: @ChrisG - OK  - I'm able to get the value of the URL parameter (as noted by AKX)  But seem to be stuck on the correct comparative syntax to check the parameter value against the array.  Even in the sample he provided, I'm not sure of how I can use that to make a page modification.  Please advise.

Comment: All you need is `if (partnerArray.includes(utmParam)) { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Let's split this into two problems. First, getting the value of the `utm` parameter:

```
function getUTM() {
  return new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("utm");
}
```

Then, figuring out whether it's one of the known partners, and returning the one it might be.

```
const partnerArray = ["test", 'test2'];
function getPartner() {
  const utm = getUTM();
  return partnerArray.find(partner => partner === utm);
}
```

`getPartner()` will return `undefined` if the query string's `utm` parameter doesn't match either known partner.

Comment: Think you want `location.search` not `location.query`

Comment: @AKX -- thanks.  This is helpful.  I'm stuck at once the getPartner() function compares to the partnerArray - of how I can use that to do make some page modifications.  I need something like:  if ( (getUTM) !== (getPartner) ) do something else {do nothing}.  Please advise.

Comment: @JPFotoz `if(getPartner()) { ... a known partner was found ...} else { ... wasn't. }`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all those that gave input.  Here's my solution for future readers with parts from the comments.

1st: Establish an Array:

```
var partnerArray1 = ["test1", 'test2'];
var partnerArray2 = ["test3", 'test4'];
```

2nd: Check what is in the URL's UTM parameter value

`var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("utm");`

3rd: Make a function to check the value against the Array:

```
function checkUTM() {
    if (partnerArray1.indexOf(urlParams) !== -1){
    //do some cool stuff here
    }

    if (partnerArray2.indexOf(urlParams) !== -1){
     //do some more cool stuff here
    }
}
```

*Short of figuring out how to pass values into the function and check that, I went with the slightly more messy way, but it accomplished my goal.  If there are improvements to the above, please feel free to provide clear updated samples.*